# React: passing component's state to container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can a component's state be passed to its container? I'm working on something like this:

```
export class MyContainer extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        someText: PropTypes.string,
        isDisabled: PropTypes.bool,
    };

    onSave = () => {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.saveDetails(this.props.someText));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SaveComponent onSave={this.onSave}>
                <SaveContent
                    someText={this.props.someText}
                    isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled}
                />
            </SaveComponent>
        );
    }
}

export class SaveContent extends Component {
    state = {
        someText: this.props.someText,
        disabled: this.props.isDisabled,
    };

    onInputChange = (e) => {
        const field = {};
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        field[name] = value;
        this.setState(field);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                name="someText"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.someText}
                disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

The components (SaveComponent and SaveContent) were done by someone else and I'm just trying to integrate the API calls to the UI. The form is in a component which is nested in a component that has a `save` functionality. From what I understand, the container is supposed to just pass data and event handlers to the components. How can I get the SaveContent's `state.someText` so that I can pass it to `actions.saveDetails` in the container's `onSave` method?

Comment: normally you would lift state up, However I recall React has a way to do that, I'll go check it out

Comment: Ok React's Context is the way to pass data to parent, anyway the docs says "don't use it" (and they're emphasizing it very much), but they also mention that `react-router` uses it, for you I recommend lifting the state up even if it requires some hard work from you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to save `someText` to state of `MyContainer` and pass it down to `SaveContent`. Because of uni-directional binding in React, parent can pass down data to child but child can only trigger event with some data that will parent component handle and save.

I would do it like this:

```
export class MyContainer extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
     dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
     someText: PropTypes.string,
     isDisabled: PropTypes.bool,
 };

 state = { someText: this.props.someText, }

 onSave = () => {
     this.props.dispatch(actions.saveDetails(this.state.someText));
 }

 onInputChange = (field) => { this.setState(field); }

 render() {
     return (
         <SaveComponent onSave={this.onSave}>
             <SaveContent
                 onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
                 value={this.state.someText}
                 someText={this.props.someText}
                 isDisabled={this.props.isDisabled}
             />
         </SaveComponent>
     );
 }
}

export class SaveContent extends Component {
 state = {
      // someText: this.props.someText,
      disabled: this.props.isDisabled,
  };

 onInputChange = (e) => {
     const field = {};
     const { name, value } = e.target;

     field[name] = value;
     // this.setState(field);
     this.props.onInputChange(field);
 };

 render() {
     return (
         <input
             type="text"
             name="someText"
             onChange={this.onInputChange}
             value={this.props.value}
             disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
         />
     );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, data binding is uni-directional, meaning it only flows one-way. For the data to become available to a parent component, you will need to trigger an event from the child component when the value has changed and make the parent component keep the new value in its state.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a call back down to child component, which returns you the state. The following is not tested, but something like this:

```
class Nested extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.state={
            clicks: 0
        }
    }

    onClickHandler() {
        const { clicks } = this.state,
              { callBack } = this.props
        this.setState({ clicks: clicks++ }, () => callBack(this.state))
    }
    render() {
        <button onClick={ this.onClickHandler }
    }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
    callBack = (childState) => {
        // Do whatever with childState here
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            <Nested callBack={ this.callBack } />
        </div>
    }
}
```